# Обновление данных вывода

Tags: java, arduino

имеется программа, цель которой собирать данные о процессоре, видеокарте, ЖД и др.
 Есть блок switch:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        switch (s) {
            case "GPUname":
                arduino.serialWrite(sensor.gpuname());
                break;
            case "GPUtemp":
                arduino.serialWrite(sensor.gputemp());
                break;
            case "on":
                arduino.serialWrite('1');
                break;
            case "off":
                arduino.serialWrite('0');
                break;
            case "exit":
                arduino.serialWrite('0');
                arduino.closeConnection();
                break label_1;
            default:
                System.out.println(s + " - не является командой");
                break;
        }
    }
```

В нем есть кейс `GPUtemp`, который возвращает температуру компьютера. Как реализовать обновление данных вывода? Чтобы мне не приходилось постоянно писать "GPUtemp",а оно обновлялось, скажем, каждые 5 секунд. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А когда прекратить вывод?

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы метод : 'sensor.gputemp();' вызывался каждые 5 секунд?

Comment: Ну если вам нужно обрабатывать пользовательский ввод и реагировать на него, и одновременно с этим контролировать температуру независимо от действий пользователя, то первая мысль -- нужно использовать многопоточность. По-честному `arduino` вроде бы ее не поддерживает, но люди как-то выкручиваются: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002984/does-arduino-support-threading         И кстати, метку `arduino` следовало поставить.

Comment: В Spring есть @Schedule, а в JavaSE - ScheduledExecutorService. Они позволяют запускать методы циклично с промежутком.